# Get color palette from App Engine image (Blobstore, Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, color-palette

Is it possible to get a set of dominant colors from an App Engine Image (stored as a blob)?

With PIL, I can do this:

```
import Image
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
out = im.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)
```

In App Engine, I get hold of the image like so:

```
image = images.Image(blob_key=blob_key)
```

Is it possible to get a palette from here?

Comment: Since PIL is available in App Engine, I'm having trouble understanding your question.  If PIL does what you need, what isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAE [images.Image](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#google.appengine.api.images.Image) class doesn't appear to offer a similar/pallette-based functionality.

But PIL is one of the GAE [Built-in Third-party Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) which you can use instead. You'd need to:

- request the library in your `app.yaml`:

  ```
  libraries:
  - name: PIL
    version: "1.1.7"
  ```
- explicitly use the `Image` class from `PIL` (may need to import it as a different name if you're also importing/using the `Image` class from GAE's `images`, to avoid a naming conflict):

  ```
  from PIL import Image
  im = Image.open('image.jpg')
  out = im.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)
  ```

Comment: thanks Dan! it kinda slipped my mind that I can use PIL on GAE:)